# How does one inject mock dependencies into a controller created in a directive's closure in a unit test?

Tags: controller, closures, karma-runner, directive, iife

say I have this directive:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('App.Directives')
    .directive('import', importDirective);

function importDirective () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/import/import.tpl.html',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: ImportCtrl
    }
}

ImportCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'NotificationManager', 'ImportService', 'FileReaderService'];

function ImportCtrl($scope, NotificationManager, ImportService, FileReaderService) {
    'use strict';

    var me = this;

    me.uploadImported = function() {
        //do stuff
    };
}
})();
```

How can I mock the dependencies in controller function in Karma without going back to declaring the controller globally as .controller('controllerName')?

I haven't been able to figure it out with the closure created in the directive after we switched to IIFE's and ripped out controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got this working.

```
beforeEach(module('App.Directives', function($provide) {
    notificationManagerMock = new app.mock.NotificationManagerMock($q);
    errorHandlerServiceMock = new app.mock.ErrorHandlerServiceMock($q);
    stateMock = new app.mock.StateMock($q);
    sessionMock = new app.mock.SessionMock($q);

    $provide.value('NotificationManager', notificationManagerMock);
    $provide.value('ErrorHandlerService', errorHandlerServiceMock);
    $provide.value('$state', stateMock);
    $provide.value('Session', sessionMock);
}));
```